# Append different data frames uploaded in dash plotly - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash

Is there a way that I can upload a .xlsx or .csv through a dcc.Upload and then upload another .xlsx or .csv to append to the first data frame in dash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `dcc.Store` component as in [this link](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store)